# PHP5 module makes Apache 1.3 segfault

Tags: php, php5, segmentation-fault, apache-1.3

I am trying to get PHP4 and 5 to work with Apache 1.3. PHP4 is compiled as a module and currently works fine, although Apache does display the following warning upon starting:

```
Loaded DSO libphp4.so uses plain Apache 1.3 API, this module might crash under EAPI! (please recompile it with -DEAPI)
```

So I compiled PHP5 using the latest source. I get the same warning, twice now for each PHP module, but then Apache gets a segmentation fault when loading the PHP4 + PHP5 modules.

I have tried compiling PHP5 with apxs and without. It does appear to be using the -DEAPI flag. Maybe this isn't related to the segfault. The flags I am using to configure PHP5:

```
./configure --with-mysql --with-zlib --disable-cgi --with-apxs=/www/bin/apxs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't load both modules at the same time because they export the same symbols. This inevitably leads to crashes. You have to use (F)CGI for one of them.